# How to remove WSL directory icon from desktop?

Tags: windows, windows-11, windows-subsystem-for-linux, wsl2

How to remove this?

[image]

I've tried to remove this icon through WSL. On path `/mnt/c/Users` there is `desktop.ini` file, I think that file represents desktop icon of WSL directory. `rm -r desktop.ini` doesn't work nor does `sudo rm -r` work. When I try to execute these commands I get `rm: cannot remove 'desktop.ini': Permission denied` and I can't access directory properties.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Desktop.ini is a regular Windows file. It has absolutely nothing to do with WSL. It’s also in use, while File Explorer is running, and your actively viewing your Desktop

Comment: Have you tried selecting it and hitting the `[delete]` key? I don't know if that will work because I have no such icon and have never seen it on the desktop level.  I have been using WSL since the early betas so I have no idea how you got that on your desktop.

Comment: Is it a requirement that you remove this icon using WSL, or have you tried native Windows methods of removing the icon?

Comment: For those who are voting to close as "Needs detail or clarity", the question is perfectly clear as is. For some reason, the WSL "network share" is showing up on the user's Desktop. Normally this would show in File Explorer only.  As seen in the screenshot, there is no "Delete" option available for it, and thus it's unlikely that pressing the Delete key will work either.  When I select *Properties* on my File Explorer "Linux", I also get the same error as in the lower screenshot.  The question is a good one - Hopefully someone will have an idea how it got there and how the user might remove it.

Answer (score 0):

This can be hidden through a registry tweak. Add the following key:

```
[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\HideDesktopIcons\NewStartPanel]
"{B2B4A4D1-2754-4140-A2EB-9A76D9D7CDC6}"=dword:00000001
```

I had the same issue after installing OpenSUSE Tumbleweed and this worked for me. I like to have a clean desktop with no icons, so I didn't like this.

I found the solution here: https://www.brainbytez.nl/windows/windows-11-hide-remove-wsl-linux-icon-from-desktop/